Method Not allowed 405 not allowing post methods as get methods working
I have created a   web api in asp.net web api      as  all methods work  perfectly on localmachine but
throguh m siite where i  hosted my site  on vercel
when i call   throgh this  get methods work but post methods not work
as
backend   api is in my system
when i call
const onCreateCustomer = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    //setLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", customer.c_name);
    formData.append("email", customer.c_email);
    formData.append("password", customer.c_password);
    formData.append("phone", customer.phoneno);
    formData.append("address", customer.address);
    formData.append("disease", customer.disease);

    if (lat !== null && lon !== null) {
      formData.append("latitude", lat);
      formData.append("longitude", lon);
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://www.quettacafe.com/FoodDeliverySystems/api/customer/signup`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            Accept: "*/*",
          },
        }
      );

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        throw new Error(
          errorData.message || `HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`
        );
      }

      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("Signup response:", data);

      const latestCustomer = await fetchLatestCustomer(lat, lon);

    

      navigate("/LoginCustomer");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Signup error:", error);
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
    

and my web api function is  (c#)
  [HttpPost]
  public HttpResponseMessage Signup()
  {
      try
      {
          var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

          // Retrieve form data
          var name = httpRequest.Form["name"];
          var email = httpRequest.Form["email"];
          var password = httpRequest.Form["password"];
          var phone = httpRequest.Form["phone"];
          var address = httpRequest.Form["address"];
          var latitude = httpRequest.Form["latitude"];
          var longitude = httpRequest.Form["longitude"];
          var disease = httpRequest.Form["disease"];

          var account = db.customer.Where(s => s.email == email).FirstOrDefault();
          if (account != null)
          {
              return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Already exists");
          }
          else
          {
              customer cus = new customer()
              {
                  name = name,
                  email = email,
                  password = password,
                  phone = phone,
                  address = address,
                  disease=disease
              };
              db.customer.Add(cus);
              db.SaveChanges();
              return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, cus);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
      }
  }

cors are enabled
I've added line  enabling cors
POST https://www.quettacafe.com/FoodDeliverySystems/api/customer/signup 405 (Method Not Allowed)
my route is configured   correctly here is my   route.config
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Fooddeliverysystems
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

  [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]    


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace Fooddeliverysystems
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}

I've tried  to make method post to work
i tried to add headers
both from front end and backend
i changed url to http   localhost
its woring locally  on localhosted webiste
but  from my www.quettacafe.com   domain its not working
my other get methods are working correctly

Changes the API response from HttpResponseMessage into IActionResult. The when the returning the values from the controller make sure to return as a Ok(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, cus)); result thats the way on how a success request should be handled.
When accessing the context make sure to use the IHttpContextAccessor _http. this is the standard and make sure to access is always like this to the context. since this allows much more control. But make sure to always run the activation in the program.cs as well for this. You can use this builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();.
Since your doing a await make sure to use the async keyword as well infront of the function since this make it wait until the await line completed in order to pass through the threads.
Make these changes and let know. Thanks.

I've tried that  its being the same  result always
so i decided to move to  DOTNET CORE 6  as it is  best of available  choices
thanks for your answer . Hope you'll help my future Questoins as well
